# Pyside pinging a list of ip's

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I am writing a program in python using PySide and I parse a file for IP address and ping them to see if they are up, and display it in a QTreeWidget.  The problem I am having is that the program pings all the clients before outputting the data, causing to the program to "freeze" while its pinging.  How can I ping the IP addresses and print the output without my program freezing?

Comment: Give us some code, so we can help you fix it

Answer (score 0):

You could ping your addresses from a `QThread`, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore

class PingThread(QtCore.QThread):
    addressState = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool, QtCore.QString)

    def __init__ (self):
       super(PingThread, self).__init__()

    def start(self, addressList):
       self.addressList = addressList

       super(PingThread, self).start()

    def run(self):
        for address in self.addressList:
            status = True
            ping   = os.popen('ping -q -c2 {0}'.format(address), 'r')
            while True:
               line = ping.readline()
               if not line:
                   break
               if line.find('100% packet loss') > 0:
                   status = False

            self.addressState.emit(status, address)
```

You'll need something like this in your main widget:

```
self.pingThread = PingThread()
self.pingThread.addressState.connect(self.on_pingThread_addressState)
self.pingThread.start(myListOfAddresses)
```

And a slot named `on_pingThread_addressState`, of course.